# Make excel recognize foreign date format

Tags: microsoft-excel, import, regional-settings

I am trying to import a text file (tab-separated columns) into excel. The log file uses `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS,mmmm`  (where mmmm is milliseconds), which excel treats as string.

How can I get excel to recognize it as a date, so I can sue it as X axis for charts, reformat it etc?

(System is W7 Ultimate set to use an English/US UI, Excel is German)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column after import and then convert the strings into an Excel datetimes with:

```
=DATE((MID(A1,7,4)),(MID(A1,1,2)),(MID(A1,4,2)))
 +TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
```

You can also add the fractional part if you need that resolution with:

```
=DATE((MID(A1,7,4)),(MID(A1,1,2)),(MID(A1,4,2)))
 +TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
 +VALUE(MID(A1,21,4))/(86400*10000)
```

These examples assume your string is in cell A1.

Comment: Thanks! (Of course, I had to replace DATE with DATUM, MID with TEIL, and the commas with semicolons - whoever thought of localizing formulas deserves a slap on the forhead. With a sledge hammer...) ---- can't vote you up yet, unfortunately.