# Have a slash-separated date recognized by Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, date-format

I received an Excel file with a column filled with *slash-separated* dates in a given column.

The dates isn't directly recognized by Excel as being so. Thus, it is not sorted correctly when I use the sort tool. I am able to turn this cell into date format by going into it, hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit, then just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But this is too long because my file have hundreds of lines...

When I use the format dialog, date separator are either `-` or `.`. Is it possible to use a custom format to turn my column into an accepted date format?
[image: Formatting Excel slash-separated dates]

I saw [here](https://superuser.com/questions/154920/make-excel-recognize-foreign-date-format) I could use a formula in a collated cell to do the job.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to turn this column into a date format, that would avoid using vba, if there is any other as the above.

**Edit**: I'd rather avoid changing my PC's behavior, so I'd also prefer ***not to change the locale*** like advised [there](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/excel-2010-how-to-reset-date-locale-default/95c3f64b-6ed6-4c7b-8a61-c46353cfeca6) of the whole system. Maybe changing it only for a workbook could work? But how?

Comment: Using the formulat in another column is probably the easiest way

Comment: Use US locale or custom format maybe?

Comment: Try pressing "CTRL+H" and replacing "/" with a "." and then reformatting the cells to a date. If this does not work then you can use the "DATEVALUE" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin, replacing the `/` with `.` did the trick.

To avoid replacing every `/` in my sheet, I had to format the column with a specific color and use the *find with specific format* option:

[image: find with specific format]